# Writing to file JSON dump from Python 'with open' exception handling

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have one dataframe "students" that I am writing to a json file if and only if the weight column in calculated_df == 100, if it does not equal to 100, then it should write to the json file an "error."

```
try:
    with open(input("Please enter an output path: "), 'w') as op:
        json.dump({
            'students': student_key['student'].to_list()
        }, op, indent=2)
except:
    for i, row in calculated_df.iterrows():
        if row['weight'] != 100:
    raise Exception json.dump({print("error:" "Invalid weight")},op)
```

Comment: `print()` returns None. Why do you want to use that inside the dict? Also, please fix the indentation of the code; your `raise` line is not part of the if statement

Comment: Since you still want to use `op` in the except block, you need to have your `with open` block at the top, and the try json.dump except statement entirely inside that `with open`.

Comment: If you also want to catch exceptions the open might raise, you'll need two separate try/except statements, one outside the `with open` and one inside.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to raise an exception. Your `try` statement is only valid for if the file cannot be written to (for example, permissions error)

Start with this

```
import json

filename = input("Please enter an output path: ")
data = {'students': student_key['student'].to_list()}
if 100 not in calculated_df['weight'].values:  # replace with correct logic; don't need a loop to check all values
  data = {"error": "Invalid weight"}

with open(filename, 'w') as op:
    json.dump(data, op, indent=2)
```

Or if you did want to `raise`, then

```
with open(filename, 'w') as op:
    json.dump(data, op, indent=2)
    if 'error' in data:
      raise Exception('An error occured')
```

Comment: I'd still keep a try/except around the `with open()`, to gracefully handle file-opening errors, but +1 regardless.